# Python: Are these default values being passed to the __init__ function necessary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a screenshot from a lecture that I am going through at school:

[image: screenshot from my class lecture]

My question is, if the class data fields are already being defined:

```
slices=16
temperature=75.0
```

Do those values (16 and 75.0) also need to be passed to the `__init__` method or can you just pass the variables names, because they are already assigned to those values?

Not sure why/if you would need to pass the default values when they are the exact same as what the variables are already set to? so instead of:

```
def __init__(self, slices=16, temperature=75.0)
```

Could you just do:

```
def __init__(self, slices, temperature)
```

**Updated new question**
If you removed the initial class-level variables at the top, and are only defining them in the constructor class, are they only scoped to the constructor class? Or are they available throughout the entire class, even though you didn't define them at the very top (class-level)?? Example:

```
Class Pizza(object):
    # no class-level slice or temp variables
        def __init__(self, slices=16, temperature=75.0):
            self.slices = slices
            self.temperature = temperature
```

Or, because you are defining them as "self.slices", they are by default passed to all of the other methods when you pass (self) into the other methods?

Comment: This sounds a bit as if you are confusing *defining* a function with *calling* a function.

Comment: The class is a bit silly.  There is no way to create an object without calling `__init__`, so those data fields at class level will always be overwritten.  I would remove those class-level definitions.

Comment: I think you are right, Klaus.. And also, thank you, Tim. What you are saying makes sense. When would you define class-level definitions? For things that are not being used to construct the object in the __init__, but may be used by other methods?

Comment: @Fields: Class attributes are for things that usefully describe the class itself in some way. For example, a `Triangle` class might choose to provides a `SIDES = 3` class attribute (all caps to indicate it's a logical constant), to differentiate itself from other child classes of `Polygon`, where `Rectangle` would define `SIDES = 4`, `Pentagon` defines `SIDES = 5`, etc. A triangle having three sides is a fundamental attribute of triangles, not an attribute of any *specific* triangle, so it makes sense as a class attribute.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, Okay that makes sense. And then you could always access those by using say triangle.SIDES ? Anywhere in the entire class? Or would you have to pass that class attribute to the __init__ to create the object with that attribute? I think that is where I am confused. If by creating a class attribute, is it automatically an attribute of any object created using that class. Or, only if something is set via self.attribute in the __init__ ?

Comment: @Fields: There's four ways you could access `SIDES`: 1) When within the class definition itself (outside any method, after `SIDES` is defined, but before you dedent), you can just use the bare name `SIDES`. 2) Inside a method of the class, you can access it on `self` (assuming `self.SIDES` has not been assigned to) 3) Outside the class, you can access it on the class itself as `Triangle.SIDES`, or 4) You can access it as `instance.SIDES` for any instance of the class (just like the `self` case inside a method).

Comment: Basically, when you access an attribute of an instance, excluding some weirdness with the descriptor protocol that doesn't apply here, the attributes of the instance act like a layer on top of the attributes of the class. So when you do `self.SIDES` or `instance.SIDES`, it checks if the instance has an instance attribute of that name (which it should not; you don't assign to it in `__init__`), and if it's not found, it checks the class for it. *Assigning* to the attribute will create an instance attribute that hides the class attribute, so if you don't want that, only assign through the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use:

```
def __init__(self, slices, temperature)
```

Then `slices` and `temperature` are parameters that must be specified.

What you can do is create a variable, and then use *that* as the default for the function parameter.

```
a = "foo"

def b(c=a):
    print(c)
```

Just keep in mind that if you redefine that variable, it does not affect the default value for the function.

```
>>> a = "foo"
>>> def b(c=a):
...     print(c)
...
>>> b()
foo
>>> a = 42
>>> b()
foo
```

Comment: So, if you did def __init__(self, slices, temperature), and created the object without passing the numbers to be assigned as the slices and temperature, it would not work?

Comment: Try it. You should see an error.

Answer (score 0):

The class defined in your lecture is dumb (not *very* dumb, just pointless and misleading, as you've clearly been misled by it). There is *zero* reason to define class attributes that happen to share the same value as the default arguments to the initializer. The only thing doing that accomplishes is:

1. You can do `Pizza.slices` and `Pizza.temperature` and see that the abstract concept of a pizza (not a *specific* pizza) somehow has a known number of slices and a known temperature, and
2. If someone using the class, for whatever reason, does `del mypizza.slices`, then future access to `mypizza.slices` will still "work", but will retrieve the value from the class attribute (since the instance attribute was blown away). Sane code should almost never do this.

In all other ways, there is *no* relationship between the class level attributes and the defaults defined for the `__init__` initializer method; the moment `__init__` assigns to `self.slices` and `self.temperature`, it shadows the class level attributes so they cannot be directly accessed from that instance of the class (without deleting the instance attributes or bypassing the instance to look at the values on the class itself).

So no, you can't do:

```
def __init__(self, slices, temperature):
    self.slices = slices
    self.temperatue = temperature
```

because the *arguments* named `slices` and `temperature` have *nothing* to do with the class attributes. By removing their defaults, the user of your class is *forced* to provide their own values, and there is no default that will be provided (they could, I suppose, do `Pizza(Pizza.slices, Pizza.temperature)`, but that's an insane way to handle defaults).

To your updated question, even without the class variables,

```
class Pizza:
    # no class-level slice or temp variables
    def __init__(self, slices=16, temperature=75.0):
        self.slices = slices
        self.temperature = temperature
```

works just fine. Outside of any methods of the class, `slices` and `temperature` won't exist, but any other methods you define on `Pizza` will be able to access *that instance's* `slice` and `temperature` attributes by looking them up on `self`, just like `__init__` did when it assigned to them (with `self.slices` or `self.temperature`), and anyone who creates an instance of `Pizza`, say, with `mypizza = Pizza(12, 140)`, can do `mypizza.slices` to see the attribute for the instance they hold.

---

A note on the class attributes: In normal cases, they're stupid and nonsensical. There is an exception for dataclasses though, where you define them at class level for the express purpose of helping [the `dataclasses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) dynamically generate your code, removing the need to write a `__init__` with separate defaults entirely. For example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Pizza:
    slices: int = 16
    temperature: float = 75.0
```

is a perfectly reasonable way to write the baseline class, and it uses those annotations and defaulted assignments to generate as `__init__` for you (along with reasonable default implementations of `__repr__` and `__eq__`, and other special methods if you pass specific arguments to the `@dataclass` decorator, saving you a ton of boilerplate required for minimal expected class functionality). It does leave the class attributes in place, which is arguably a bad idea, but at least you're getting something useful out of the deal, it's not just repeating the same defaults in two essentially unrelated places, one of which is completely useless.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow so i'm kind of trying to figure out how I can add code into the comments. It looks like you use `code` ? I need to look up what dataclasses are because they haven't mentioned them at all. And yes, they have thoroughly confused me throughout the entirety of the class. It's been super frustrating. The instructor is non-existent, tons of syntax errors in the slides / lectures so when you go to do what they just taught you, doesn't work. Is there a way that I can share another screenshot with you that I just took? Regarding the class attributes and the examp

Comment: @Fields: You don't need to know `dataclasses` right now; they're a relatively new feature so most code you see won't be using them yet, and you still need to know how to do it all manually, I just supplied the example for the future. If you have other questions that you can't figure out, I recommend posting a new question; StackOverflow comments aren't well-suited to detailed stuff like this. You should avoid posting screenshots; post the text you're curious about, with comments; makes it easier for people with screen readers and to allow people to copy-paste the code.

Comment: This is the example for encapsulation, and I find it so confusing why you would need both the class private variables and the self.__variables in init
`#!/usr/bin/python

class ProtectedPizza(object):
   __slices=16
   __temperature=75.0

def __init__(self, slices=16, temperature=75.0):
   self.__slices = slices
   self.__temperature = temperature

def hasSlices(self):

   if self.__slices > 0:
      return True
   else:
      return False

def getSlices(self):
   return self.__slices

def setSlices(self, newVal):
   if type(newVal) is int:
      self.__slices = newVal;`

Comment: Ugh, see, I even took the time to try and do the correct indentation and stuff and it still came out looking super difficult to read. I know! It's difficult to go through and read the comments sometime and make sense of what they're saying. I don't know anyone else that codes so yeah it's the best I've got. Need a mentor haha.

Comment: @Fields: Yep, that's why I said comments don't work well (you can't do blockformatted code with syntax highlighting). Beyond that, ugh, that code is not Pythonic at all. Clearly written by someone who used to use Java and carried over their habits to Python. The method names don't follow PEP8 (which recommends `lowercase_with_underscores`, *never* `snakeCase`), and you basically *never* write methods named `getX` and `setX`  (that's what the `@property` decorator is for, in the rare cases you need it). Also, strictly speaking, the `__` prefix on a variable means "private", not "protected".

Comment: Other issues: `if type(newVal) is int:` precludes `int`-like things (e.g. `numpy` scalars) that it should allow, as well as `int` subclasses, and it just silently rejects them rather than reporting the error (admittedly, my preferred idiom of `self.__slices = operator.index(newval)` isn't for newbies, but `isinstance(newval, int)` is, and it's better). And while it's not terrible, just verbose, the body of `hasSlices` (`has_slices`!) could just be `return self.__slices > 0`, no need to test it to select between `True` and `False` when `self.__slices > 0` is already producing `True` or `False`.